# Unignorable spoken battery warning on Windows 8

Tags: battery, low-power, text-to-speech-voices

I found [this old article](http://lifehacker.com/5769174/give-your-mac-a-more-attention+grabbing-low-battery-warning) on how to give a Mac OS X laptop a battery warning that can't be ignored.

I was wondering how I could (if I can) achieve the same thing on Windows (8). Perhaps with Microsoft David/Sam Computer voice bugging me to plug it in?

It is important that it will pester me regardless of other running processes or wheter my speakers are technically muted.

Also, would it be possible on Linux?

Comment: You would have to write your own software to do this.

Comment: On Vista I'd settle for a warning that was simply noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 already has an unignorable battery warning! It looks exactly like the SmartScreen filter, which is a solid-color panel that spans the entire width of the window. See the below images:

[image]

[image]